# Show or hide text widget based on boolean value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/switcher_button) package which toggles a boolean variable value. I am using this boolean variable to show/hide a text widget. Although the value changes,the widget isn't affected at all. What am I missing here?

```
 SwitcherButton(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  value: showDiscount,
                  onColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                  offColor: Colors.grey,
                  onChange: (value) {
                    showDiscount = !value;
              }),
              
if(showDiscount) Text('Hello')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are making `showDiscount = !value;` make use using `statefullWidget`.
but your mistake is not using `setState()`
replace

```
onChange: (value) {
     showDiscount = !value;
        }),
```

with

```
onChange: (value) {
   setState((){  showDiscount = !value;})
        }),
```

I suggest using the `Visibility` widget. it controls visibility of any Widget. it doesn't take size while it is not visible.

here is the demo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:switcher_button/switcher_button.dart';

class HideAndSeek extends StatefulWidget {
  HideAndSeek({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HideAndSeekState createState() => _HideAndSeekState();
}

class _HideAndSeekState extends State<HideAndSeek> {
  bool _isVisible = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Hey Check It "),
            SwitcherButton(
              value: true,
              onChange: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _isVisible = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _isVisible,
              child: new Text('Boom'),
            ),
             if (_isVisible) Text("Hoiaaaaaaa"),
            Icon(Icons.upcoming),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this did not work with switcher. I am wondering if it has to do with switcher package or not. Have you tried to toggle the isVisible with switcher ?

Comment: yes it works with `switcher widget`, check update answer,

Comment: Which switcher version are you using?

Comment: switcher_button: ^0.0.4

Comment: Magical. That did it. Thanks alot. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set state and change the test as bellow.

```
SwitcherButton(
                          key: UniqueKey(),
                          value: showDiscount,
                          onColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                          offColor: Colors.grey,
                          onChange: (value) {
                            setState(){
                                showDiscount = !value;
                            }

                      }),
                      
        showDiscount ? Text('Hello') : Container(),
```

Comment: When I do setState inside onchange, the switcher does not function at all

Comment: are you using some state manager like mobx or getx?

Comment: Yes I am using getx  in my project but no necessarily in this class

Comment: You need to change the state of the class to be rebuild and show the difference, depending of which way are you change the states.

Answer (score 0):

Use Stateful Widget if you are using Stateless Widget and add setState method inside onChange

```
 onChange: (value) {
          setState(() {
            showDiscount = !value;
          });
        }),
```